# Trying to read a plist file from the Document directory using swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, file

Ok, Managed to put this code together, created a plist file with Xcode which I copied {using iTunes} to the app folder, it doesn't work...

```
import Foundation

class getBeaconConfiguration {
var myBeaconsDict: NSDictionary?

func getBeacons() {
    let documentsPath : AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true)[0]
    let sourcePath:NSString = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/beacons.plist")

    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: sourcePath as String)
    print("dict",dict)

   }
```

}

The path is good, and the plist is there, but the NSDictionary returned is a null pointer it seems. How do you do this in swift 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Get Create a URL to the file and then create a dictionary from it.

```
let filename = "beacons.plist"

guard
    let fileURL =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    else { fatalError("Unable to get file") }

let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

A little different in Swift 2.0, String no longer has stringByAppendingPathComponent, and you should be using this method when working with file paths.

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let sourcePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("beacons.plist")
let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: sourcePath as String)
print("dict: \(dictionary)")
```